# MS SQL How to Update multiple rows with single value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could anyone tell me how to update a number of rows with a same value..?

for example if I have an employee table like,

```
employee id   salary
    1           100
    2           230
    3           120
    4           360
    5           190
```

if I want employees 1, 2, and 5 to have the same salary, say 300...
How do I update that using a single query?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see a reason why this question needed to be closed !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
update employee
set salary = 300
where [employee id] in (1,2,5)
```

or

```
update employee
set salary = 300
where [employee id] = 1
   or [employee id] = 2
   or [employee id] = 5
```

Comment: The first option is better, really.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: In this case, yes. But I added the other option since it clearly is a beginner's question and other possibilities might be helpful.

Comment: @juergend True, but I personally think it's better to present only the 'best practice' method. Anyway, I +1 your answer.

Comment: I could've done it with 'or' but wanted to know the first method you've written...

Comment: @Auguste: Just use `update employees set salary = 300 where salary = 150`

Comment: @juergen d:  That's exactly what I tried.  But it didn't work.

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't then ask a detailed question about it.

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
Update
    YourTable
SET 
    Salary=300
WHERE
    [employee Id] IN (1, 2, 5)
```